# Como realizar com parser a autenticação em um site que precisa de login e parsear seu conteúdo HTML?

Tags: login, autenticação, parser

Preciso parsear o conteúdo de tabelas HTML de um site, mas para acessar a página é necessário fazer login. Como faço o parser realizar este login, esta autenticação?
Pode ser com qualquer parser.
Já procurei, mas não encontrei nada ainda.

[image: Login por alert]

Comment: Como é o login dessa página, é um form html, ou uma autenticação http?

Comment: Ao entrar ele abre um "alert" com os campos pra preencher. Ainda sou novo com parsers e é a primeira vez mexendo com login..
Vou verificar mais a fundo para poder informar o tipo de autenticação mais detalhadamente

Comment: Essa janela é chamada de Autenticação HTTP, só para conceituar melhor,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso não haja **nenhum tipo de segurança contra isso**(o site pode simplesmente exigir que se digite) , você poderá usar a chamada da URL com o seguinte formato:

> https://user:pass@sitequevcquer.com/

Há um debate sobre isso neste link [aqui](https://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters)

Comment: Muito obrigado! Está com erro de ssl handshake agora, que pesquisarei para corrigir.

Grato pela ajuda Rodrigo!